# Am I calling findMany correct?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, prisma

Trying to find multiple rows using prisma.findMany returns bad invocation. I believe this is a runtime error.
Heres the schema model, findMany() call, prismaMock, and the error. I believe that it has something to do with how Im creating my prisma mock which will lead to findMany returning an empty arr.

```
    Error:
          Invalid `prisma.derivedTimeSeries.findMany()` invocation in
          C:\Users\cmb\vlly\vlly-api\src\v1\metrics\timeseries.ts:18:53


    model DerivedTimeSeries {
        id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
        projectIDToDate String @unique
        projectID Int
        date DateTime
        viewCount Int
        uniqueViewCount Int
        dwellTime Int
    }
    let dataArr:any[] = [];
    try {
        timeseries = await prisma.derivedTimeSeries.findMany({
            where: {
                project: projectID,
            },
            select: {
                date: true,
                viewCount: true,
                uniqueViewCount: true,
                dwellTime: true, 
            }
        });
        for(let i = 0; i < timeseries.length; i++) {
            let dataObject = {
                timestamp: timeseries[i].date,
                views: timeseries[i].viewCount,
                uniqueViews: timeseries[i].uniqueViewCount,
                dwellTime: timeseries[i].dwellTime,
            }
            dataArr.push(dataObject);
            }
    }
    const createMockTimeseries = (prismaMock: any, projectID: number, viewCount: number) => {
      const mockTimeseries: Timeseries = {
        id: 1,
        projectIDToDate: '1.12/7/2022',
        projectID: projectID,
        date: new Date(),
        viewCount: viewCount,
        uniqueViewCount: 0,
        dwellTime: 0,
      };        prismaMock.DerivedTimeSeries.findUniqueOrThrow.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockTimeseries); 
}; export { createMockProjectOverview, createMockTimeseries };
```

Comment: What is the specific error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
     where: {
                project: projectID,
            },
            select: {
                date: true,
                viewCount: true,
                uniqueViewCount: true,
                dwellTime: true, 
            }
```

I think you should change the where clause from

> project:  projectID

to

> projectID

```
     where: {
                projectID,
            },
            select: {
                date: true,
                viewCount: true,
                uniqueViewCount: true,
                dwellTime: true, 
            }
```